# Use Multiple Bootstrap carousel in same page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have to use multiple bootstrap carousel in single page.If i am using different id for each carousel its possible. But I want use same class or id..it is possible?I have tried like this
$('.myCarousel').carousel();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').each(function(){
      $(this).carousel({
          interval: 3000
      });
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7DLyk/4/